# How can I generate all 32-bit numbers from 0x0 to 0xffffffff?

Tags: c, 32-bit

I want to test every possible valid input to a program I wrote. It accepts 32-bit values. So how would I write a loop to generate all the inputs from 0x0 to 0xffffffff? I'm unsure how I would increment the value (it wouldn't be incremented by 1, right?)

This is what I tried, but I'm not sure if it works:

```
unsigned int start = 0x0;
while (start < 0xffffffff){
    //do stuff
    start += 0b1;
}
```

Comment: Incrementing by 0b1, 0x1, or 1 is all the same. The code you have is perfectly valid.

Comment: By 0b1, you meant 0x1, right? (unless your compiler supports binary integer literals) And yes, it should work, except you're forgetting about `0xFFFFFFFF` since the loop stops at that value. You'd need to use `unsigned int start = 0; do { /* do stuff */ start += 0x1; } while (start != 0);` to test all values. Note that `start += 1` can also be written as `++start`.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for catching my error on the while loop condition. Much appreciated

Comment: @ChronoKitsune ++x x++ are not the same as x+=1. The result eventually is the same but the behavior completely different.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 True. I'm aware of the potential for unexpected results and UB, but as standalone expressions, the results are the same.

Comment: Why is this tagged [floating-point]?

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work, because it doesn't do the final value `0xFFFFFFFF`.

If you change the code to this:

```
unsigned int start = 0x0;
while (start <= 0xffffffff){
    //do stuff
    start += 1;
}
```

Then (for 32-bit unsigned integers) the code will loop forever.

To do it properly you need a loop that depends on unsigned integers wrapping on overflow, like this:

```
unsigned int start = 0x0;
do {
    //do stuff
    start += 1;
} while(start != 0x0);
```

Comment: one remark - unsigned int does not have to be 32 bits as OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is missing the largest number

```
uint32_t start = 0;

do {
//do stuff
}while(++start)
```